# How to inverse ShortTimeFourier?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to reconstruct some signals from Fourier Series components. To be exact, short-time Fourier, however, the length of the original signal is either shorter or longer than the original signal depending on the partition length and/or offset I use.

```
chirp = Table[
   Cos[200. \[Pi] t + 2400. \[Pi] t^2], {t, 0., 0.4, 1/8000.}];
stft = ShortTimeFourier[chirp, 512, 16, HannWindow];

chirpRecon = InverseShortTimeFourier[stft, 512, 16, HannWindow];

Length@chirp = 3201
Length@chirpRecon = 3712
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like due to the padding, the data at the start and end can not be reconstructed. Further, the transformed data must be scaled by the inverse shift length to get the original data back.

```
hirp = Table[
   Cos[200. \[Pi] t + 2400. \[Pi] t^2], {t, 0., 0.4, 1/8000.}];
stft = ShortTimeFourier[chirp, 512, 16, HannWindow];

chirpRecon = InverseShortTimeFourier[stft, 512, 16, HannWindow]/16;
ListLinePlot[{chirp[[;; 800]], chirpRecon[[;; 800]]}]
ListLinePlot[{chirp[[-800 ;;]], chirpRecon[[-800 ;;]]}]
```

[image]